# Comparing characters in a string sequentially in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to compare a character in a string to the next character in the string.  For example, if I have a string:

```
s = 'vzcbotdebobeggglakyl'
```

I want to be able to compare the first character with the second character, and if the second character is greater than or equal to the first character (alphabetically speaking, a < b, g > e, y = y, etc) I want to add 1 to another variable (Basically a counter).  If it isn't, I want to reset the counter to 0.  And basically repeat the entire process for the length of the string.  If the counter becomes greater than the maxlen variable, then add one to maxlen (Or make maxlen = sublen).  My attempt so far is (And I think it is working):

```
s = 'vzcbotdebobeggglakyl'
sublen = 1
maxlen = 0
startnum = 0
for char in s:
    stopnum = startnum + 1
    if stopnum < len(s):
        charone = s[startnum]
        chartwo = s[stopnum]
        if charone <= chartwo:
            sublen += 1
            startnum += 1
            if sublen > maxlen:
                maxlen = sublen
        else:
            startnum +=1
            sublen = 1
    else:
        sublen = 0
print 'Longest substring is', maxlen, 'characters.'
```

Now, what I also would like to do is have a line print out that substring of characters.  I have been working on this for five hours and can't get it right.  I have tried so many different things that I am basically confused even worse now than when I started.  In the above example, I want it to say

```
Longest substring is begggl, which is 6 characters.
```

Comment: `begggl` but `g` isn't *greater than* `g`... :)

Comment: It's greater than or equal to, which is what the code says ;)  (Damnit, I keep hitting enter and sending the comment rather than a new line :P  )  I do realize that I said that if the character greater than, to add one to the counter, but what I meant was greater than or equal to.

Comment: your problem text is incorrect then: "*I want to be able to compare the first character with the second character, and if the second character is greater*" :P

Comment: @GarethRees What does "whinning" mean , please ? Is it a metaphor for "whipping" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def longest_ascending(s):
    matches = []
    current = [s[0]]
    for index, character in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if character >= s[index]:
            current.append(character)
        else:
            matches.append(current)
            current = [character]
    matches.append(current)
    return "".join(max(matches, key=len))
```

**Explanation:**

- `matches` is a list of all substrings with "ascending" characters.
- `current` is the substring of ascending characters being built as we iterate through the string. We start out with the first character of the string.
- We now iterate through the remaining string character by character. `enumerate()` helps us keep track of the index of the *previous* character (because the enumeration starts at `0` and we iterate the string from the second character onwards).
- If the current character is "greater or equal" to the previous one, we add it to the current substring and move on.
- If not, we add the current substring to the list of substrings, and seed the next substring with the current character.
- After the iteration is over, don't forget to add the current substring to the list as well.

Comment: Works great, but there are a couple of instances of it not working?

Comment: @Ernesto: Can you be more specific?

Comment: s = 'rdxkuqeshqwxahabrtvw' returns 'hqwx' and 4 as the longest substring?  It should be 'abrtvw' and 6?

Comment: s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' also returns an error ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: @Ernesto: Ah yes, I forgot to handle the case when the longest match is at the end of the string. Well spotted!

Comment: Perhaps I am doing it wrong, but if I enter a string (such as a = 'dghertsds') with that updated formula, nothing will show up on the screen.

Comment: def longest_ascending(s):
    matches = []
    current = [s[0]]
    for index, character in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if character >= s[index]:
            current.append(character)
        else:
            matches.append(current)
            current = [character]
    matches.append(current)
    return "".join(max(matches, key=len))
print(longest_ascending('dghertsds'))

Comment: Nevermind, I am so freaking tired, t does not come before s ;)  I guess if you have multiple substrings that are the same length, it displays the first.  Answer accepted.  Thanks for putting up with me.

Answer (score 2):

This is less obvious, but seems to work:

```
seq = "vzcbotdebobeggglakyl"

import itertools
result = max(
    (
        list(next(sub)) + [b for a, b in sub]
        for ascending, sub in itertools.groupby(zip(seq,seq[1:]), lambda x: x[0] <= x[1])
        if ascending
    ),
    key=len
)

print ''.join(result)
```

Comment: I will look at that one tomorrow, I think my brain is already about to explode from getting Tim's suggestion working (Well, the hours I've spent on it beforehand didn't help).  Thanks for the effort, and I promise I will get around to looking at your answer.  I appreciate your time.