# Create a dynamic string

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I'm trying to build some kind of "dynamic substring" that is build out of a loop in a given `string`. The rule is that I need to find the longest `substring` in alphabetic order and in case I have a tide, I need to evaluate both and print the one with the bigger value.

I read that in python characters are already given a numeric value, so `a` is lower than `b`; knowing this I wrote the following:

```
s = "abcsaabcpaosdjaf"
ans = []
# Loop over the string
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i] < s[i+1]:
        #evaluate if it is in order and build the new string
        ans = s[i]+s[i+1]
    #print the result        
    print(ans)
```

the problem I have is that I don't know how to dynamically - I am not sure if this is the right way to say it - build the substring `ans`, right now I have the `s[i]+s[i+1]` but that only gives me a list of two characters that are in fact in alphabetic order, and it is fixed to only two. How can I do it in a way that it builds it as it goes?

Comment: what is the output that you're expecting?

Comment: in this case where I have s="abcsaabcpaosdjaf", the print out would be "aabcp" as this is the longest alphabetic ordered substring.

Comment: Could you explain the rules? I don't get them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Comments hopefully explain enough, but ask away if you don't understand.

```
s= "abcsaabcpaosdjaf"
best_answer = ''
current_answer = s[0]
# Loop over the string
for i in s[1:]:
    # look to see if this letter is after the
    # last letter in the current answer.
    if ord(i) > ord(current_answer[-1]):
        # if it is, add the letter to the current
        # answer
        current_answer += i
    else:
        # if it is not, we check if the current
        # answer is longer than the best
        # answer, and update it to the best
        # answer if it is.
        if len(current_answer) > len(best_answer):
            best_answer = current_answer
        # We then set the current answer
        # to just the last letter read.
        current_answer = i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
s= "abcsaabcpaosdjaf"
result = max(
    (
        list(next(sub)) + [b for a, b in sub]
        for ascending, sub in itertools.groupby(zip(s,s[1:]), lambda x: x[0] <= x[1])
        if ascending
    ),
    key=len
)

print (''.join(result))
```

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19563499/1836483)